# Applying lineHeight or lineSpacingExtra is not working

Tags: android, layout

I have simple xml layout with `TextView` on it.

```xml
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView9" />
```

[image]

I'm trying to apply `lineSpacingExtra` attribute to the second `TextView`. It makes no effect. Same with `lineHeight`.

Is there any mistake in my understanding of how these attributes work?

```xml
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="20sp"
            android:text="TextView1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="20sp"
            android:text="TextView2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView9" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android:lineSpacingMultiplier):

> The value will not be applied for the last line of text.

So if you add multi-line text to the `TextView` (for example: `TextView1\nTextView2`), it will work.

Answer (score 1):

use multiple line.
use "dp" instead of "sp":

```
android:lineSpacingExtra="20dp"
```